# How to sum values of two text fields and display the result in a third textfiled?

Tags: javascript, html

I got this table where I want to Sum the values of two textfields:

```js
function myAdd() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell4 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell5 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input name='totalOf' type='text' class='fields' id='totalOf'>";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<input name='price' type='text' class='fields' id='price'>";
 cell3.innerHTML = "<input name='acceptedKgMeters' type='text' class='fields' id='acceptedKgMeters'>";
 cell4.innerHTML = "<input name='nameofArticle' type='text' class='fields fieldstwo' id='nameofArticle'>";
 cell5.innerHTML = "";
}
function myDelete() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(1);
}
```

```html
<!--This is the table*-->
<form id="fromTable" name="formTable">
  <table width="100%" border="1" id="myTable">
    <tr id="myTable">
      <th width="7%" id="cell1" scope="col">Row.Num.</th>
      <th width="33%" id="cell2" scope="col">Column1</th>
      <th width="31%" id="cell3" scope="col">Column2</th>
      <th width="7%" id="cell4" scope="col">Column3</th>
      <th width="22%" id="cell5" scope="col">Total</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
<!--These are the buttons. The ones that I add and delete rows.-->
  <p>
    <input name="addRow" type="submit" class="addRowbtn" onClick="myAdd();" value="Add row" />
    <input name="deleteRow" type="submit" class="addRowbtn" onClick="myDelete();" value="Delete Row" />
  </p>
```

When you run the snippet and click the "Add row Button" a new row is added. In that second row textfields excist. So when i enter for example 3 in the textfield below Column 2 and 5 in the textfield below Column 3, I want it to show the result in the textfield below column Total.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: As I'm sure you can see from the error message, your `onkeyup` calls a `sum` method that doesn't exist in your demo. So have you tried writing that function yet?

Comment: If (with two rows) column 2 has two entries `3` (in the first row) and `5` (in the second row) you want to show `8`? Where?

Comment: @user6738792: The `onkeyup` is in your HTML you're assigning. Did you write this code, or did you find it online?

Comment: oh, yeah i see it. sorry

Comment: It seems you removed one `onkeyup` but not the other. Your question is vague. We don't know where you're stuck. I'd think you'd want to write a `sum` function instead of removing the event handler. If you're looking for a "how to" tutorial, there's plenty of information online that'll help.

Comment: dont use duplicate id's.

Comment: @DavidThomas no, whe you run the snippet  and click the "Add row Button" a new row is added. In that second row textfields excist. So when i enter for example 3 in the textfield below Column 2 and 5 in the textfield below Column 3, I want it to show the result in the textfield below column Total.

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME. I need a working code. Everything is updated and there isn't `onkeyup='sum();'`

Comment: i have a working js fiddle but works only for one row if you add more rows it doesn't work so i am trying to figure out how to fix that. Also have some problems with adding values for the second time

Comment: @edisoni.1337 okay, let me now when you finish it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here it is, it should work, it works for me**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>



<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<!--This is the table*-->

  <table width="100%" border="1" id="myTable">
    <tr id="myTable">
      <th width="7%" id="cell1" scope="col">Row.Num.</th>
      <th width="33%" id="cell2" scope="col">Column1</th>
      <th width="31%" id="cell3" scope="col">Column2</th>
      <th width="7%" id="cell4" scope="col">Column3</th>
      <th width="22%" id="cell5" scope="col">Total</th>
    </tr>
    </table>

<!--These are the buttons. The ones that I add and delete rows.-->
  <p>
    <input name="addRow" type="submit" class="addRowbtn" onClick="myAdd();" value="Add row" />
    <input name="deleteRow" type="submit" class="addRowbtn" onClick="myDelete();" value="Delete Row" />
  </p>


  <script>
  function myAdd() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var cellt1 = cell1;
    var cellt2 = cell2;
    var cellt3 = cell3;
    var cellt4 = cell4;
    var cellt5 = cell5;
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input name='totalOf' type='text' class='fields' id='totalOf'>"
    cell2.innerHTML = "<input name='price' type='text' class='fields' ' id='price'>";
    cell3.innerHTML = "<input name='acceptedKgMeters' type='text' class='fields' onkeyup='sum()' id='acceptedKgMeters'>";
    cell4.innerHTML = "<input name='nameofArticle' type='text' class='fields fieldstwo' id='nameofArticle'>";
    cell5.innerHTML = "<input readonly='readonly' id=total>"
}
function myDelete() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(1);
}

function sum()
{
var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("acceptedKgMeters").value);
var z = x + y;
document.getElementById("total").value = z ;
}
  </script>
  </html>
```

I have removed the `onkeyup()` from the second column and kept it only in the third column, but it works both ways.

I have also changed the table generation to `var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);`

As it was creating a sort of LIFO system causing the addressing to be reversed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked as charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a sum function to your script and call it  like **sum(this)** and instead of calling the sum function onkeyup you should call it on onchange .Try the script below.

```
 function myAdd() {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = "<input name='totalOf' type='text' class='fields' value='0' class='totalOf'>";
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input name='price' type='text' class='fields' onchange='sum(this);' id='price'>";
        cell3.innerHTML = "<input name='acceptedKgMeters' type='text' class='fields' onchange='sum(this);' id='acceptedKgMeters'>";
        cell4.innerHTML = "<input name='nameofArticle' type='text' class='fields fieldstwo' id='nameofArticle'>";
        cell5.innerHTML = "";
    }
    function myDelete() {
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(1);
    }
    function sum(element){
        //Get This Table Row 
        var  tr = element.parentNode.parentNode;
        //Get Column 1 and Column 2 Values 
        var column1 = tr.childNodes[2].childNodes[0].value;
        var column2 = tr.childNodes[3].childNodes[0].value;

        //Check if column1 is undefined 
        if (!column1){
            column1 = 0;
        }
        //Check if column2 is undefined 
        if (!column2){
            column2 = 0;
        }

        //Sum column1 and column2 and return value to last td in table 
         tr.lastChild.childNodes[0].value = parseFloat(column1)+parseFloat(column2);
        }
```

Comment: Yes it does , before i posted it i checked it localy :(

Comment: Okay, I guess i've made a mistake while putting it in my `js` file